# PHP Curly bracket, what's meaning in this code

Tags: php, mybb

I have this code (for getting a query from database, in [MyBB](http://www.mybb.com) source):

```
$query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM {$this->table_prefix}{$table}";
```

My question is: What's meaning of `{$table}`? and what the difference between $table and `{$table}` (what's meaning of `{}`)??

Thank you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The braces simply sequester the variable names from the rest of the text (and other variable names).  Generally, this syntax is used for consistency's sake; it's sometimes necessary when you have variables that run into other letters, but many programmers use it all the time so that they never have to think about whether it's necessary.

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: +1 for "many programmers use it all the time so that they never have to think about whether it's necessary."  If you always use the long form then going back and changing things rarely breaks things

Answer (score 4):

It's the PHP syntax for inlining expressions within double quotes. If you have simple expressions such as variable name, you can just use $table without bothering about {}.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM {$this->table_prefix}{$table}";
```

Would execute identically to

```
$query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM $this->table_prefix$table";
```

Using curly braces is good practice for readable code when using variables within strings (especially for those without syntax hightlighting / color blindness).

sample:

```
<?php
class simple
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->table_prefix = "blablabla";
    }

    function doSomething()
    {
        $fields = "1,2,3";
        $table = "MyTable";
        $query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM $this->table_prefix$table";
        return $query;
    }  
}
$a = new simple(); 
print $a->doSomething();

?>
```

Ta

Comment: No, it wouldn't execute identically. The second would error, as `$this->table_prefix` won't be understood without the brackets.

Comment: So I can write: `$query = "SELECT $fields FROM $this->table_prefix$table";` instead of `$query = "SELECT ".$fields." FROM $this->table_prefix$table";`????