# PHP Concatenation using {}

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [curly braces in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string)

I still don't know what it's called. Like:

```
$name = 'xxx';

echo "This is a string {$name}";
```

What do you call that operation? Concatenating a variable using {} in to a string.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [curly braces in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string), [PHP Curly bracket, what's meaning in this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563728/php-curly-bracket-whats-meaning-in-this-code),

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not concatenation ; this is **variable interpolation** ; see the [**Variable parsing**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) section, in the PHP manual.

Basically, you can use any of the two following syntaxes :

```
echo "This is $variable";
```

Or :

```
echo "This is {$variable}";
```

And you'll get the same result in both cases -- except the second one allows for more complex expressions.

Concatenation would be something like this :

```
echo "This is my : " . $value;
```

Where the content of the variable `$value` is concatenated to the string, using the [**concatenation operator `.`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Comment: I've referred to this as string/variable expansion as well. Would this be correct?

Comment: By a loose definition of "concatenation" (appending one string to another) then jun's example is concatenation (as the interpolation is at the end), albeit not via the standard concat operator.

Comment: The manual says "variable parsing" ; I generally say/hear "variable interpolation" ; https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Variable_%28programming%29 seems to indicate that interpolation, substitution, and expansion are all valid terms.

Answer (score 2):

It's often called string or variable interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

[How does {} affect a MySQL Query in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370426/how-does-affect-a-mysql-query-in-php/5370445#5370445)

Don't let the question itself throw you - this answer gives you exactly what you are looking for.

And it's not concatenating; this is concatenating:

```
$myvar = "This is a string ".$name; // <<< Notice I'm concatenating the variable
                                    //     using the . operator
```